# npm multiple module and main entry points

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules

I'm building a package that supports CommonJS and ES Modules. I have it working fine for a single entry point. I wrote my code as an ESM and use Babel to compile it to CJS before publishing. The pertinent bit of my `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "main": "cjs/",
  "module": "esm/",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest ./test",
    "clean": "rm -rf cjs",
    "build": "npm run clean && babel esm --out-dir cjs",
    "prepare": "npm test && npm run build"
  }
```

So my `index.js` is in `esm/index.js`, and `cjs/index.js` doesn't exist until the package is published. When the package is included using `require` (e.g. `const myPackage = require('my-package')`), it will pull from `cjs/`. If it's imported (e.g. `import myPackage from 'my-packge'`), it will pull from `esm/`.

My problem is that I want to be able to import other files from the package (e.g. `import adapter from 'my-package/adapters/mysql'` or `const adapter = require('my-package/adapters/mysql')`). But if I include it in this way, the file won't be found.

I can import it using the full path (e.g. `import adapter from 'my-package/esm/adapters/mysql'` or `const adapter = require('my-package/cjs/adapters/mysql')`). But I don't want to have to explicitly specify the module type in the path. It seems like node already knows how to tell the difference between CJS and an ES module (it knows to require from `main` and import from `module`), so I'm hoping it's possible to do the same with multiple files.

Is there any way to include a package, as I've described above, without having to explicitly specify the path to either `esm/` or `cjs/`?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you can export multiple named items from your entry point:

`export adapters from './adapters'`

etc.

Comment: @rayhatfield You mean export them in the `index.js` file? I thought about doing that, but then I have to import and destructure them from index (e.g. `import {adapters: {mysql}} from 'my-package'`).

Comment: You can `export default from ...` in addition to named exports if you want to be able to import something without destructuring. You could also do something along the lines of:
`import {Adapters} from 'my-package';
// do something with Adapters.mysql`

Comment: @rayhatfield That's what I'm trying to avoid. I might be wrong, but I have a feeling that tree shaking won't be able to prune the unused adapters if I import all of them. Plus that's potentially a lot of extra code to parse (a bunch of database adapters) if I'm just going to use one. It seems like having each adapter in its own file, imported on its own, would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Are these frontend modules meant for the browser?

Comment: @slebetman I was using them on the server (node).

Comment: Then there is zero need for tree shaking. Just don't worry about it. Generate all the files

Comment: @slebetman Oh sorry, I should have clarified. I was building the package to be used wherever. I was just having this specific issue in node.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//the project(package) mcktools's package.josn
"main": "dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "dist/index.js",
    "./cmd": "dist/nodejs",
    "./web": "dist/web",
  }

//js import the package mcktools:
import {file} from 'mcktools/cmd'
```